# Group numbers into closest groups

Tags: algorithm, numbers, nearest-neighbor

For example, I have the numbers 46,47,54,58,60, and 66. I want to make group them in such a way as to make the largest possible group sizes. Numbers get grouped if their values are within plus or minus 10 (inclusive). So, depending on which number you start with, for this example there can be three possible outcomes (shown in the image).

What I want is the second possible outcome, which would occur if you started with 54, as the numbers within 44 to 64 would be grouped, leaving 66 by itself, and creating the largest group (5 items).

I realize I could easily brute force this example, but I really have a long list of numbers and it needs to do this across thousands of numbers.. Can anyone tell me about algorithms I should be reading about or give me suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Actually, I think I figured out how to do it. I simply iterate across and find the largest group, then remove that group from the list (and save it), then recursively call the function again, each time removing/saving the largest group until I have the stragglers..

Comment: Its not completely clear what you mean by "largest possible group sizes".  Is it based on average, median, etc.

Comment: I want to maximize the number of items in groups, doesn't matter the average number.

Comment: All of the numbers are in groups, so I still don't really know what you're looking for.  Do you want the largest possible largest group, followed by the largest possible largest group of the remaining numbers, etc.?  That is what your example implies, I think.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. The number of items in the largest group?

Comment: Aaron, yes, exactly. I think I figured it out, doing it recursively and finding the single largest group each time.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply sort the array first. Then for every i th number you can do a binary search to find the right most number that's within ith number + 20 range, let the position of such right most index is X. You have to find the largest (X-i+1) for all ith numbers and we are done :)

Runtime analysis: Runtime for this algorithm will be O(NlgN), where N is the number of items in the original array.

**A better solution:** Let's assume we have the array ar[] and ar[] has N items.

1. sort ar[] in non decreasing order
2. set max_result = 0, set cur_index = 0, i=0
3. increase i while i

   set max_result to max(max_result,i-cur_index+1)

   set cur_index=cur_index+1

   if cur_index

**Runtime Analysis:** O(N), where N is the number of items in the array ar[] as cur_index will iterate through the array exactly once and i will iterate just once too.

**Correctness:** as the array is sorted in non decreasing order, if `i < j` and `j < k` and `ar[i]+20 > ar[k]` then `ar[j]+20 > ar[k]` too. So we don't need to check for these items those are already checked for previous item.

Comment: I know its been ages but can you give an example code that works in your solution. This is exactly what I need. Many many thanks!

Comment: I figured out first paragraph, but your 'better solution' is still a mistery. :) Concretely, you increase i and cur_index at the same time? This is confusing to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wanted to do. Sorry I didn't explain myself very well. Each iteration finds the largest possible group, using the numbers that are left after removing the previous largest group. Matlab code:

```
function out=groupNums(y)
d=10;
out=[];
if length(y)==1
    out=y;
    return
end
group=[];
for i=1:length(y)
    group{i}=find(y<=y(i)+d & y>=y(i)-d);
end
[~,idx]=max(cellfun(@length,group));

out=[out,{y(group{idx})}];
y(group{idx})=[];
out=[out,groupNums(y)];
```